# How can I efficiently read pixel values from a CIImage generated from CMSampleBuffer data?

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, core-image

I am reading sample buffers from an iOS AVCaptureSesion, performing some simple image manipulation on them, and then analyzing pixels from the resulting images.  I have done this using openCV for the image processing, but I'd like to switch to core image, which I hope will be more efficient for these simple operations.  However I am completely stuck on how to read the pixel values from the resulting CIImage.

When I have a UIImage backed by a CGImage I can use the cgImage dataProvider to access the underlying pixel data (example below).  But what is the analog with CIImage?

Here is my general flow:

```
    // Getting sample video data
    var session : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    // processing the sample buffer with core image
    func handleSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) 
    {      
       let cvImage: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
       let ciImage: CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: cvImage)

       let filteredImage = processWithCoreImage(image: ciImage)

       //
     // How can I efficiently get pixel values from filtered image here?
       //
    }

    func processWithCoreImage(image: CIImage) -> CIImage
    {
      // process with a core image filter chain
        let filter1 = CIFilter(name: “…”)!
        filter1.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter1.setValue(…, forKey: …)
      …
        let outputImage = filter.outputImage
        return outputImage
    }

  // With a regular UIImage I was doing something like this to get pixel data
  // However CIImage does not have a cgImage backing it in this case.
  public extension UIImage {
      func getPixelValueGrayscale(x: Int, y: Int) -> UInt8 {
          let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
          let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
          let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(y)) + Int(x)) 
          return data[pixelInfo]
      }     
  }
```

I have tried using CIContext to get a CGImage backed UIImage as follows, but this proved horribly inefficient - was taking a good fraction of a second for each frame (hundreds of times longer than the equivalent openCV operations).

```
// re-used CIContext
let cgImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, from: ciImage.extent)
let img = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
```

I should also mention that my filtered image is tiny (I am scaling it way down).  I don't know if this is causing some problem.

What am I missing?  Thanks.

UPDATE: After some experimentation it turned out that the scaling options in CI are just a lot slower than those available in OpenCV. It feels wrong to include OpenCV in my project just for scaling, but... for the moment.

Comment: I up-voted the "answer" from @matt even though it really didn't answer (sorry). It sounds like you wish to work with the camera in "real-time". (He was correct, this isn't an efficient way.) I'm no expert, but here' a link to someone who is: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2015/12/cartooneyes-compositing-cartoon-eyes.html?view=magazine. If that link doesn't work? Look at the rest of his blog posts. *Technically*, you *do* want to use CI, just *not* the way you posted. (Sorry for the use of italics - trying to emphasize.)

Comment: Thanks for reporting back! I was just wondering how this had turned out. Please feel free to answer your own question, and even (in a couple of days) to accept your own answer.

Comment: Good question....  Getting the UInt8 values from a CGImage is a good solution, but I think manipulating the values directly from a CIImage or even better the PixelBuffer would be more efficient.